PrismaClientInitializationError: error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL
EDIT : Deleted dist and node_modules folder and ran the commands again. Worked
I have prisma nest js project with postgresql db.
I am getting the following error after running npm run start :
PrismaClientInitializationError: error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
  -->  schema.prisma:13
   | 
12 |   provider = "postgresql"
13 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
   | 

Validation Error Count: 1

Things I have tried and outputs :
npx prisma migrate dev --name init

output : Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "spotapp", schema "public" at "localhost:2345"
npx prisma generate         
output :
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
I have .env file at root
I am on macOS

This might be related the the latest prisma release 5.16.0.
See https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/24634.
Try downgrading to 5.15.0.
You can see your version by running npx prisma version.
This has been fixed in 5.16.1 https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/24634#issuecomment-2194644640.

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

in your main.ts file
Need to install module
yarn add dotenv
yarn add @types/dotenv --dev

or using npm
npm install dotenv
npm install @types/dotenv --save-dev

